# Horizontal Navigation In Text Based Browsers

Tags: html, css, w3m, elinks

In the old days of table based layouts it was relatively simple to make a horizontal nav bar that rendered horizontally in both graphical and text based browsers.

Now the standard way of making a horizontal nav-bar is by using an unordered list and styling it with CSS.

Is there any way to make a ul list appear horizontal in something like w3m or elinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience in those browsers but `ul/li` have default CSS built in. If the browsers recognise that, it has to be overriden to get inline lists. Perhaps rather use a group of anchors which are inline by default.

You can use a `div` to hold the list but semantically, the `nav` element is more appropriate.

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Although it doesn't use ul, this works perfectly for making a modern horizontal nav that works in both text based and graphical browsers alike!

Answer (score 0):

The `<nav>` tag can be used for this. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp